# Move div inside another div using jQuery - repeating sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has divs loaded in the order label, field, label, field, label,field etc

I need to move each label inside the 'field' div which immediately follows it leaving me with the div pattern of field, field, field, field etc..

The code shows the label div with the class '.cf-label' and the field with the class '.cf-field'

```html
<div class="cf-label">...</div>
<div class="cf-field">...</div>
<div class="cf-label">...</div>
<div class="cf-field">...</div>
<div class="cf-label">...</div>
<div class="cf-field">...</div>
<div class="cf-label">...</div>
<div class="cf-field">...</div>
```

Can this be done with jQuery?

UPDATE

So the code provided by Mamun worked but certain field types (Caldera forms for Wordpress) inject scripts inline and so I get the following pattern which breaks the original code at the point where the first script tag is found in the markup ..

```html
<div class="cf-label">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<div class="cf-field">...</div>
<div class="cf-label">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<div class="cf-field">...</div>
<div class="cf-label">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<div class="cf-field">...</div>
<div class="cf-label">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<div class="cf-field">...</div>
```

How can I move the `<script/>` elements to the bottom of the container and thus 'preserve' the label/field pattern throughout the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through all the label elements

and [`.prependTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/prependto/) that

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the beginning of the target.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.cf-label').each(function(){
  $(this).prependTo($(this).next('div.cf-field'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="cf-label">Label 1</label>
<div class="cf-field">Div 1<div>
<label class="cf-label">Label 2</label>
<div class="cf-field">Div 2<div>
<label class="cf-label">Label 3</label>
<div class="cf-field">Div 3<div>
```